# grep or awk to find a multiline pattern (with spaces) in a file

Tags: awk, grep

I want to check (true/false) if a file contains a rather complex pattern that includes spaces and spread over more than 1 line. For example:

```
$ cat myfile 

hello world
bye
```

both are not working:

```
awk '/\nhello world\nbye/' myfile
grep "\nhello world\nbye" myfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest

```
if grep -Pzq "\nhello wolrd\nbye" myfile; then
  echo "Matched."
fi
```

There `-P` tells grep to use Perl regexes (which support newlines), `-q` suppresses the output, and `-z` uses a null byte as line separator instead of newline, which means that text files will be considered one long "line." (Binary files may be split into several null-byte-delimited chunks, which should not be a problem unless your pattern contains null bytes)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' '/\nhello world\nbye/' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl` this will work:

```
perl -ln0e '/\nhello world\nbye/ && {print "true"} || {print "false"}' myfile
true
```

Switches used:

`-l` : prints a new line after every print statement

`-n` : will loop through input

`-0` : will make the whole input a single record

`-e` : evaluates the code